# What does pyflakes w804 signify?

Tags: python, pyflakes

I'm working on a decorator that will retry running a function up to N times as follows:

```
def retry(exceptions, truncate=5, delay=0.25):                                     
      """Retry the decorated function using an exponential backoff strategy.         
      If the function does not complete successfully a TimeoutException is           
      raised."""                                                                     
      def wrapper(func):                                                             
          @wraps(func)                                                               
          def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):                                              
              tries = 0                                                              
              while tries < truncate:                                                
                  try:                                                               
                      return func(*args, **kwargs)                                   
                  except exceptions, e:                                              
                      print "%s, Retrying in %d seconds..." % (str(e), delay)        
                      time.sleep(delay)                                              
>>                    delay += delay                                                 
                      tries += 1                                                     
              else:                                                                  
                  raise TimeoutException()                                           
          return wrapped                                                             
      return wrapper
```

To me the code looks sensible, but on the line highlighted pyflakes complains, reporting:

> W804 local variable 'delay' (defined in enclosing scope on line x)
>   referenced before assignment

This doesn't quite make sense to me. `delay` *has* been assigned a value, and I presumably should be able to reference it as a I please. Can someone explain what the error is, and if reasonable, how I can fix it?

Comment: For anyone who encounters this in the future, [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) explains the restriction in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will actually crash if you try running it. The problem is that in nested scopes like `wrapped` (and `wrapper`), you can *read* outer variables but not *assign* to them.

This is what [the `nonlocal` keyword](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) in 3.x is for (which would make `delay` increase across all "instances" of `wrapped` from a single call to `retry`). To replicate this in 2.x, you need to do something like `delay_lst = [delay]` and access it as `delay_lst[0]`.

If you want the modifications to be local to `wrapped`, just make a new variable and initialize it with the value of `delay`.

Comment: Ah-- doesn't quite make sense to me why it's so, but the technique that you mention shows up in [the code I was basing mine on](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry) from the python wiki.